# How to fix infinite loop during bisection search

Tags: python, bisection, epsilon

My code passes test cases but if anything about ~949,000 is input it enters an infinite loop.

I need to calculate the best rate at which to save a portion of a monthly income to save in order to afford a down payment in 36 months with 2 significant digits. I'm thinking this has something to do with me not quite understanding how epsilon is calculated - I've tried calculating epsilon as 0.0001 * total_cost, 0.0004 * portion_down_payment, and 0.0001 * annual_income all to no avail.

```
#House Hunting ps1c

low = int(0)
high = int(10000)
percent_saved = (low + high)/2.0

current_savings = 0
annual_salary = int(input("What is your starting anual salary? "))
total_cost = 1000000
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
epsilon = 100

r = 0.04

total_months = 0
steps = 0
while True:
    current_savings = 0
    monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
    for i in range(1,37):
        current_savings += (current_savings*r/12)
        current_savings += (monthly_salary * (percent_saved / 10000))     
        total_months += 1
        if total_months % 6 == 0:
            monthly_salary += monthly_salary * semi_annual_raise
    steps +=1   

    if abs(current_savings - portion_down_payment) <= epsilon:
        print("Steps in bisectional search: ", steps)
        best_savings_rate = str(percent_saved / 100)
        print("Best savings rate: ", (best_savings_rate + "%"))
        break
    elif (portion_down_payment - 100) - current_savings > 0:
        low = percent_saved
        percent_saved = int((low + high) / 2.0)
    else:
        high = percent_saved       
        percent_saved = int((low + high) / 2.0)

    if percent_saved >= 9999:
        print("It is not possible to afford this in 3 years")
        break
```

## Test Case 1

```
Enter the starting salary: 150000
Best savings rate: 0.4411  
Steps in bisection search: 12
```

## Test Case 2

```
Enter the starting salary: 300000
Best savings rate: 0.2206 
Steps in bisection search: 9
```

## Test Case 3

```
Enter the starting salary: 10000
It is not possible to pay the down payment in three years
```

My code passes all test cases but when the input is too high it enters an infinite loop that I don't know how to reconcile.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your code to see why certain tests pass and others do not?

Comment: Or even just some print statements, to print out the variables on each pass through the loop, to see if they are behaving as you expect?

Comment: The for loop that accumulates thirty-six months of savings **:**  put it in a function and test it - does it work?  if so you know that is not it - that would leave errors in the `if/elif/else` logic or the way you calculate/determine the new savings percentage.

Comment: `int((low + high) / 2.0` - why are you converting to an int?  What does `(percent_saved / 10000)` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially when annual salary becomes higher the optimal savings rates becomes smaller. When the optimal savings rate becomes smaller then the level of precision you require for

```
abs(current_savings - portion_down_payment) <= epsilon
```

becomes higher.
When you cast percent_saved to an int in

```
percent_saved = int((low + high) / 2.0)
```

it artificially limits the precision and then code enters an infinite loop.

Remove the cast and the code will work always.

Comment: I did this and also removed my int conversion of low and high earlier in the program. To limit significant digits I used `best_savings_rate = best_savings_rate[0:5]` `print("Best savings rate: ", (best_savings_rate + "%"))`